# Can this code work with fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

The following code works with `scanf`, but I don't know how to make it work with `fgets` (the search always fails), could you help me please (I'm a beginner in C) ?

And if possible, could you tell me why it doesn't seem to work with `fgets`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>




char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};


int main(){
    char word[80];
    puts("Hello, type a word: ");
    fgets(word, 80, stdin);
//    scanf("%79s", word);

     for( int i= 0; i < 5; i++){
        if( strstr(tracks[i], word) ){
            printf("Found the track: %s\n", tracks[i]);
            break;
        }
     }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` leaves the newline in the string, `scanf` doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `fgets(word, 80, stdin)` and `scanf("%79s", word)` is that `fgets` one will include `'\n'` before null terminator, while `scanf` would not. That is why `strstr` returns `NULL` with `fgets`: there is an unmatched `'\n'` at the end.

There are two general approaches to making the strings equal again - you could either remove the `'\n'` from the end of the `word` (preferred), or add `'\n'` to the end of the words that you search (not recommended).

```
int len = strlen(word);
if (len != 0 && word[len-1] == '\n') {
    word[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: +1 Minor addition: `scanf("%79s"` will not scan any white-space whereas `fgets()` will (up to the first `'\n'`).